# Unable to get declared event in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, delegates

I have converted the following c# code to vb.net.

Issue is unable to get declared event in one class to access in another object.

Please see details as follow;

c# code is as follow:

```
public Dropdown(CheckedComboBox ccbParent)
{
   this.ccbParent = ccbParent;
   InitializeComponent();
   this.ShowInTaskbar = false;                      
   this.cclb.ItemCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler(this.cclb_ItemCheck);
}

private void cclb_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
   if (ccbParent.ItemCheck != null)
   {
      ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e);
   }
}
```

vb.net

```
 Public Class CheckedComboBox
Inherits ComboBox


Public Event ItemCheck As ItemCheckEventHandler   

....

End Class
Private cclb As CustomCheckedListBox
   Public Event ItemCheck As Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler
   Public Sub New(ByVal ccbParent As PlexisCheckedComboBox)
   MyBase.New()
   Me.ccbParent = ccbParent
   InitializeComponent()
   Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
   AddHandler cclb.ItemCheck, AddressOf cclb_ItemCheck
End Sub

Private Sub cclb_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs)
   If (Not (ccbParent.ItemCheck) Is Nothing) Then
      ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e)
   End If
End Sub
```

In the converted vb.net code im getting error in the following line as

```
If (Not (ccbParent.ItemCheck) Is Nothing) Then
   ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e)
```

Please help me how to resolve it .  `ItemCHeck` is not able to access.

Comment: Please pay more attention to your code formatting. It's all over the place at the moment, making your question *really* hard to read. You've asked 53 questions - you should be able to format a post properly by now.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx

Comment: Thanks who has formatted. I was involved in formmating but could not... will see help soon. Please any one guide me what is the cause in above issue. tried raise event examples in many optins but not work in above example. able to access other properoties declared in `ccbParent` but not able to access `ccbParent.ItemCheck` event which is already declared.

Comment: It doesn't help that your constructor parameter has the same name as a property.  Please see my answer.

Comment: Please guide me why it is down vote... so, I could take care further. this is the correct issue which I am facing.

Comment: You are using non-standard/customised controls - no-one can verify if what those controls do is correct or not.  You may need to post the entire code behind all those controls (please don't) or ask a more specific question.

Comment: I want this control In vb.net and i just converted through developer fusion but, facing one particular issue which i shared above. Please guide as it is still open. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

Comment: You say you are getting an error.  Will you please tell us what that error is?

Answer (score 0):

The direct translation of your C# code is as follows;

```
Public Sub New(pCCBParent As CheckedComboBox)
    Me.ccbParent = pCCBParent
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    AddHandler Me.cclb.ItemCheck, Me.cclb_ItemCheck
End Sub

Private Sub cclb_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Please pay attention to the differences between the two languages - there are few things that can't just be translated word-for-word.

Comment: Now, it gives error at constructor - `Add Handler...` line saying -`Argument not specified for parameter e......`

Comment: also, the error is still giving for RaiseEvent about - ccbParent.ItemCheck is not found

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a `CheckedComboBox` object to test it with.  Did you create it yourself?

Comment: Please check updated question where included that event declaration. it is not able to find when access through `ccbParent.Itemcheck`.

Comment: You can't raise a base class event in a derived class (so I think the original C# example is flawed also).

Answer (score 0):

I have declared sub at outer side as below. and calling as `ccbParent.RaiseItemCheckEvent(sender,e)`.

```
 Public Sub RaiseItemCheckEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ItemCheck(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Thanks all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't raise base class events from derived classes directly - try the following:

```
Class CheckedComboBox
    Inherits ComboBox

    Public Event ItemCheck As Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler

    Protected Sub RaiseItemCheckEventFromDerivedClass(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemCheck(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class

Class DropDown
    Inherits CheckedComboBox

    Private ccbParent As CheckedComboBox

    Private Sub New(ByVal ccbParent As CheckedComboBox)
        Me.ccbParent = ccbParent
        AddHandler ccbParent.ItemCheck, AddressOf cclb_ItemCheck
    End Sub

    Private Sub cclb_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs)
        RaiseItemCheckEventFromDerivedClass(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```